# Passing compilation flags to bazel (TensorFlow)

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I am compiling TensorFlow from sources on an ARM7-equipped SoC, thus it is a non-standard compilation. Bazel fails in many cases but it is easy to fix if I could pass it some additional compilation flags: for example

```
-I/home/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_turing/508b67e7022bdc82335b30f64f498c49/tenso
rflow/external/eigen_archive/eigen-eigen-ed4c9730b545/ -I/home/root/.cache/baz
el/_bazel_turing/508b67e7022bdc82335b30f64f498c49/tensorflow/external/eigen_arch
ive/
```

How can I pass those extra flags to Bazel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[--copt](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/2.0.0/user-manual.html#flags-options) is the way to set C flags from the command line but those flag should be set already by bazel when building tensorflow.

What is the output of `bazel build -s`? Can you see the includes of gcc? (Maybe we should continue the discussion on the github issue tracker).

Comment: Hi Damien, definitely --cxxopt fixed the issue but that should be not necessary. Here my github thread: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1243